# Binding Qt with MAPI

Tags: android, c++, qt, outlook

I'm making an Android app using Qt(So, that includes QML & C++, I guess I must say), that's supposed to both send and get email from different email services(Mostly, It will be corporative email, so i think it must go through Microsoft Exchange server, and also Microsoft Outlook preferable).

The thing is that i didn't found any specific material nor documentation on those topics. I found good SMTP client for Qt, but that does not fully serves my needs, due to the fact that It is also needed to get those emails. I was wondering how it is even possible to do?

Does it will take some Java native code to get those, or is there any opportunity to somehow bind those with Microsoft Graph/Microsoft Outlook API? Really struggling out here.

Comment: It looks like they're asking how best to use msgraph from Android. Microsoft provides an SDK for this: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) Client.

There are various clients already written in C++. You'll need to find one that works on Android. Here's one I found on google: https://github.com/cutelyst/simple-mail

Comment: Thanks
Although I actually used that library just at the start, but that one does not include receiving mail
Although, I found some others on github
I'll mark question as marked when I'll figure out whether they're useful or not